# SAPUI5 Handle Enter in Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5, keydown, sap-fiori

I'm implementing custom SAPUI5 application containing simple Dialog with two inputs and one dropdown list.
As default values are saved by (begin)button from Dialog, but the requirement is to   save all data using ENTER key.

I've implemented afterOpen event for dialog with following code:

```
onAfterDialogOpen: function (oEvent) {
    var oDialog = this;

    jQuery("input").on("keydown", function (oKeyEvent) {
        if (oKeyEvent.keyCode == 13) { // ENTER
            oKeyEvent.preventDefault();
            debugger
        }
    });
}
```

and it is triggered correctly, problem is that I don't know how to get all the values from dialog and call other functions from this controller.

Any idea? Some kind of proxy function?
Thanks in advance

Comment: if you used a model, you can simple read the model to get ur data.

Comment: I'm able to use data from dialog when it is confirmed using Button, problem is that **I don't know how to get any controller functions within jQuery function** (next to debugger statement). oDialog variable is not available and this is assigned to HTML code of Input control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SAP has its own way of checking for enter. It's called onsapenter:

```
oDialog.addEventDelegate({onsapenter: *functionyouwanttocall*}, this);
```

More info can be found [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/01/26/sapui5-extending-controls-behavior-using-addeventdelegate-function/).

Answer (score 0):

this is not the correct way to handle user input. You should definitely follow the [SAP Fiori Design Pattern](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/).

If you want to see how to implement Dialog binding and handle user input you can check out my project about a S[APUI5 CRUD Application](https://github.com/StErMi/openui5-exercise/tree/step_6).

- [Dialog Binding](https://github.com/StErMi/openui5-exercise/blob/step_6/webapp/view/fragment/dialog/SaleOrderItemEditDialog.fragment.xml)
- [Handling user input](https://github.com/StErMi/openui5-exercise/blob/step_6/webapp/controller/BusinessPartnerSalesOrderDetail.controller.js)

Answer (score 0):

**sap.m.Input** has an event called "**submit**" that is triggered when you hit **Enter**

For example

```
<Input placeholder="Hit Enter to Submit" submit="handleEnterPress">
```